# Why can't NetBeans find CopyLibs for some of my projects?

Tags: netbeans, ant, build

I ran into a nasty issue this morning that cost me several hours trying to trace it down. I had inherited some code with two NetBeans projects, `A` and `B`. *They both build and run successfully*; there are no complicated Ant build tasks; just the default IDE setup.

These two projects share a large amount of code, so I factored it out into a new, third project, `Common`. After resolving references and so on, NetBeans reports no errors. Everything seems fine. I build the `Common` project without a hitch. Then things get weird.

Suddenly, when I try to build projects `A` and `B`, they *compile* just fine--but at the end of the *build*, each one breaks with the same error:

```
Copying 1 file to C:\Projects\projectName\build
C:\Projects\projectName\nbproject\build-impl.xml:723: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Projects\projectName\nbproject\build-impl.xml:543: taskdef class org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.copylibstask.CopyLibs cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

All the `.class` files show up in `build/classes`, and everything else seems to have gone smoothly, but nothing makes it to the `dist` folder. So begins my search for `CopyLibs` issues.

People suggested making sure that `org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar` was referenced correctly in the `project.properties` file (it was), and in the `<userhome>/.netbeans/version/build.properties` file as well (it was). The library *does* exist at all the places it is referenced; in fact NetBeans seems to place a copy of this jar into the `./lib` folder of all Java projects by default. I tried making brand-new projects and bringing the sources in manually, to no avail. I was mystified.

I'm posting here in the hopes that:

- Maybe someone can give me some insight into **how this happened in the first place and how to avoid it.**
- Maybe someone can tell me **why only certain projects break**, even when all have exactly the same `project.properties` file or are brand new.
- People with this problem in the future will have a better time of it.

Answer (score 28):

The closest fix I could find online is [this link](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_fix_the_libs), which only includes a partial solution. Following the instructions in that post *will not* fix the problem, because it leaves out some important stuff. Here's the solution that I eventually stumbled upon.

In NetBeans, go here:

```
Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Ant
```

At the bottom of the window, there's a box labeled `Properties`. Paste in the following:

```
libs.CopyLibs.classpath=C\:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 7.1\\java\\ant\\extra\\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

Replace `NetBeans 7.1` with your actual install path. That's actually all there is to it! The thing that makes it tricky is that NetBeans appears to do some parsing of the text in this field when you click `OK`. Specifically, **it treats backslashes as escapes**, and also **sometimes adds backslashes**.

This is why it took me so long to find: I tried the solution in the link (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Netbeans` etc), and it didn't work, but later I came back to this window to discover this: `C\:Program Files` etc. "Oh!" I thought, "I just typed it wrong! What a fool I am!" So I "corrected" it to `C:\` and tried again-- still no success. Turns out NetBeans will *add* a backslash to escape `:`, but will just delete any other single-backslashes it finds in here.

**I still don't know why this happened in the first place, or why it only seems to affect certain projects.**

Comment: Just had the same issue, does any one know why it is happening?

Comment: In NetBeans 8.0.2 it is Tools > Java > Ant, more like the screen shot for 7.3 in James' answer.

Comment: To get a fix outside netbeans, add this line to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\x.y.z\build.properties`.

Comment: Thanks. saved my day :)

Answer (score 9):

I had NetBeans 7.1.2 on my Mac, uninstalled it, and then installed 7.3.1.  I got the same errors. Here's what I had to do to fix:  Go to

> NetBeans menu > Preferences > Java tab > Ant subtab > Properties

I noted that the properties still had the old number for the app, so I had to change the 7.1.2 to 7.3.1, and then it worked.

[image]

Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: Yup, this here's the fix. Every time I re-install Netbeans, I come across this issue, and then stumble across this answer to fix it :D

Comment: This should be the right answer. Save me several hours. For another version of Netbeans, replace with your version.

Answer (score 1):

Background Info: The Ant properties are held in the build.properties  file in a user directory. This varies dependent on platform but can be found by looking in the nbproject/private/private.properties file. Then look at the path under user.properties.file and have a look in the file pointed to - you can see the paths used in the Ant build - and whether they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for my setup turned out to be in a project I included as a library. It still had the CopyLibs-2 folder and not the upgraded CopyLibs folder but the nblibraries.properties had the upgraded libs.CopyLibs stuff. I don't know how to trigger the upgrade so instead I did the following:

1. Deleted lib/CopyLibs-2
2. Right-clicked the Libraries folder and chose Add Library.
3. Imported CopyLibs Task
4. Added CopyLibs Task library

This made CopyLibs show up in my Libraries folder which seemed a little strange because it's normally hidden like the jnlp one is, but it worked without having the global libs.CopyLibs.classpath set at  Tools > Java > Ant Properties.

It took a few tries to clear stuff the right way and add it. Sometimes it would add but then show a problem and the resolve message would be '"CopyLibs" library has missing items' and 'Problem: The project uses the class library called "CopyLibs" but the classpath items of this library are missing'. I don't get why the whole process is so fussy and magical.

I also noticed on commit that the IDE had updated my project.properties to change javac.classpath from nothing to ${libs.CopyLibs.classpath}

Comment: I think it's a bug in the tooling, the CopyLibs classpath value is supposed to be set in nblibraries.properties but then that file is not included because the tools don't update the library configuration.  Totally share your frustration about magical IDEs not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, a private property had to change when I installed a newer NetBeans. Project file nbproject/private/private.properties ended with the line:

```
user.properties.file=C:\\Users\\Fred\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\12.5\\build.properties
```

"12.5" was the old NetBeans version. Correcting this to "16" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

watch this video on how to fix it

https://youtu.be/sLXfZqKoXu4

-> still works in NetBeans 20

It just involves finding the org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file from within your NetBeans folder and then declaring them in the classpath located in Tools > Options > Java and also declaring it in your Palette manager.