# NetBeans WebApplication

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, compiler-errors, java-8

I'm working on a NetBeans WebApplication which using hibernate. After changing two lines of code I've got next error:

```
ant -f C:\Users\User\Assignments\AssignmentZaposleni -Dnb.internal.action.name=debug -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=C:\Users\User\Assignments\AssignmentZaposleni debug
C:\Users\User\Assignments\AssignmentZaposleni\nbproject\build-impl.xml:797: The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up.
This property must point to 
org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file which is part
of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at 
<netbeans_installation>/java<version>/ant/extra folder.
Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library
exists or setup the property manually. For example like this:
 ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Before changing the code compiling was OK without mistake.
Change in the code are:

The code before:

```
mySQL=Restrictions.sqlRestriction(upit.substring(upit.indexOf("WHERE")));
    criteria.add(mySQL);
```

The code after:

```
mySQL=Restrictions.sqlRestriction(upit.substring(upit.indexOf("WHERE")));
    criteria.add(mySQL);
List list =session.createCriteria(Zaposleni.class).add(mySQL).list();
```

When I comment the change error persists!?
Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: The error re-occurs even after you comment your change(code). That indicates the problem is not with your code. The problem seems to be with netbeans installation. While you were adding/removing code has any one removed some files from `<netbeans_installation>/java<version>/ant/extra` folder?

Comment: I did not work anything with installation files. Only change I described! I know it is very strange but it is as I've wrote.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973377/why-cant-netbeans-find-copylibs-for-some-of-my-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have automatic NetBeans update and during you making changes in your Java code NetBeans made some updates and made changes in configuration files. Try this maybe, it can be  helpfull:

Right mouse click on project name/Properties/Libraries/Compile/

If there is no "CopyLibs Task" add it by pressing:

AddLibrary, select CopyLib Task and finaly AddLibrary/OK.